# Set font-family for UILabel with AttributedText HTML

Tags: html, ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

First of all I just want to display `Html` content in my label. `Html` simple, for example: `Some <b>bold</b> text`

I've done it by following code:

```
var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
var nsError = new NSError();
attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;  
var font = NewHTMLLabel.Font;  
string htmlContents = $"<span style='font-size: {fontSize};font-family: '{font.Name}''>" + ViewModel.HtmlText + "</span>";
NewHTMLLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(htmlContents, attr, ref nsError);
```

Here `font-size` works as expected and my `UILabel` use this size, but `font-family` doesn't take effect. If I use `font.FamilyName` instead of  `font.Name`, it's set font family as expected, but `HTML` not working (all text normal without bold text inside).

So what the problem?

Comment: Make sure your font library has this font, and you can try to modify other commonly used fonts to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem with AttributedString. If I use HTML doc type it automatically divides string to two substrings and each has different fonts (times new roman and times new roman bold). But if I set font it applies fonts for all string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in quotes around `{font.Name}`
Here is corrected code:

```
string htmlContents = $"<span style='font-size: {fontSize};font-family: {font.Name}>" + ViewModel.HtmlText + "</span>";
```